# What to use to fill holes and spaces all over dryer lint screen frame that capture lint when drying

Tags: dryer

My LG dryer lint trap has a plastic frame with numerous tiny useless nonfunctioning corners,crevasses,holes, etc which fill up with lint and require a toothpick and vacuum to clean out. I would like to fill them in with perhaps a high heat self leveling glue or something similar to prevent lint buildup.   Worst lint screens I have ever owned.

Comment: Those small gaps might be there by design, to prevent complete obstruction and overheating by allowing some air to still pass by the filter in the case of neglectful failure to clean it. If they were there from the beginning, I recommend **not** altering it.

Comment: What's wrong with leaving them filled with lint? I just clean the screen and pick off any large chunks from the crevasses with my fingers and move on with my life.